# me sale un valor vacío al consultar / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, msql

```
public function index($id)
{
    $providers = Provider::Find($id);

    $providerwal = ProviderWallet::where('provider_id', $id)->get();

    $providereport  = ProviderPay::join('providers_wallets', 'providers_wallets.id', '=', 'providers_payments.providerpay_id')
                                ->select('providers_payments.providerpay_id')
                                ->where('providers_payments.providerpay_id', '=', $providerwal)
                                ->get();

    return $providereport ;
    

}
```

tengo esta consulta en mi ProviderPayController

Tengo una vista dónde muestro los pagos pendientes de cada cliente en una tabla, ahora...cada pago tiene un botón que me lleva a los abonos realizados a ese mismo pago,
lo que quiero lograr es mostrar los abonos relacionados a un pago pendiente, todo esta correcto, en los modelos, migraciones, etc.

En $providerwal intento recuperar el ID del pago pendiente cuando se le da click al botón "ver abonos" y $providereport intenta filtrar $providerwal con la llave foránea para que me muestre solo los abonos realizados a ese pago

pero al retornar el valor de $providereport me da una salida vacía, que estaré haciendo mal?

Comment: @BetaM listo espero se entienda jeje

Answer (score 0):

Sin saber como están tus datos exactamente yo lo haría algo así.

Suponiendo que cada Provider solo tenga un ProviderWallet. Si puede tener mas de uno, deberás cambiar el ->first() por ->get() y hacer un ->whereIn.

```
public function index($id)
{
    // Como solo tengo un wallet hago un first.
    // Ya que solo voy a usar el ID especifico los campos en el select, así la query es más liviana
    $providerwal = ProviderWallet::select('id')
        ->where('provider_id', $id)
        ->first();

    $providereport  = ProviderPay::join('providers_wallets', 'providers_wallets.id', '=', 'providers_payments.providerpay_id')
                                ->select('providers_payments.providerpay_id')
                                ->where('providers_payments.providerpay_id', '=', $providerwal->id)
                                ->get();

    return $providereport ;
    

}
```